# Multiple definition of main error in catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What am I doing wrong. I checked [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/67128/ros-service-why-do-i-have-multiple-definitions-of-main/) but the add_executables seem to be ok. [This is my cmakeList.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAibTBiSUdONXZIZ1k/view?usp=sharing) 
 If i only use the server and client example it error is the same. Did I mix something up?

```
    [ 94%] Built target listener
    Scanning dependencies of target add_two_ints_server
    [100%] Building CXX object test_my_env/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o
    Linking CXX shared library /home/baum/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmy_test_lib.so
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/listener.cpp.o: In function `main':
    listener.cpp:(.text+0x15c): multiple definition of `main'
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/talker.cpp.o:talker.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o: In function `main':
    add_two_ints_server.cpp:(.text+0x2b5): multiple definition of `main'
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/talker.cpp.o:talker.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp.o: In function `main':
    add_two_ints_client.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
    CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/talker.cpp.o:talker.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [/home/baum/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmy_test_lib.so] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [test_my_env/CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225476/multiple-definition-of-main-error-in-catkin_make/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is very recommendable to have a second workspace to just build this package and I nailed it. 
My exported library was the problem. So I commented it but the WHY is still unsolved?

```
CMake Error at test_my_env/CMakeLists.txt:61 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "/opt/ros/jade/lib/libroscpp.so" to target
  "add_two_ints_server" which is not built in this directory.
```

```
## build your library, listing all required C++ source files(no headers)
#set(MY_TEST_LIB_SRC
#   src/talker.cpp 
#   src/listener.cpp 
#   src/add_two_ints_server.cpp 
#   src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)

## my library export
#add_library(my_test_lib ${MY_TEST_LIB_SRC})

## my library depends on
#target_link_libraries(my_test_lib
#                       ${catkin_LIBRARIES} #catkin libraries
#                       ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) #additional non catkin libraries
#add_dependencies(my_test_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Libraries are installed in a lib/ directory shared by all packages in entire ROS distro
#install(TARGETS my_test_lib
#        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0